# Custom Tooltips in Oracle APEX Area Chart

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a requirement according to which I need to have custom tooltips on a chart instead of default Series, Group and Value labels. I need to change these with my own custom ones.

Is there any way to have custom tooltips to a line with area chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Edit the chart region, and in the chart attribute JavaScript Code, enter the following code snippet:

```
function( options ){
    // Add new group and series labels to tooltips  

    if ( options.valueFormats.group ) {
        $.extend( options.valueFormats.group, { tooltipLabel: 'Apple' });
    } else {
        options.valueFormats.group = { tooltipLabel: 'Apple' };
    }
    $.extend(options.valueFormats.value, { tooltipLabel: 'Fruits' }); 
    return options;
}
```

2) Save the changes, and run the page.  Note that the 'Group' label will now display 'Apple', and the 'Value' label will now display 'Fruits'.